# Select Distinct From View

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sqlcommand

lets say that I have view that contains the following data

```
Name      Image
----    ----------
 A         Image1
 A         Image2
 A         Image3
 B         Image4
 B         Image5
```

Now what I want is to select only one row for each Name, doesn't matter which I just want the result to be for example:

```
Name      Image
----    ----------
 A         Image1
 B         Image4
```

another scenario might be closer to what I need here is what if we took a site that sells products each product has multiple images how to select only one image to be displayed as a cover (lets say the first one). I used Distinct but it doesn't work because each row has different image.

Thanks,

Rasha

Answer (score 2):

For the data in your question, a simple aggregation will do:

```
select name, min(image)
from t
group by name
```

If you have multiple columns *and* want all the rows from the same table:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to all rows with the same name.  The `order by newid()` does a random sort.